# Add html Using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
        <span class="mad">2</span> Stuff

</li>
```

I want this

```
            <a href="/My/Website"><span class="mad">2</span> Website</a>

    </li>
```

Can someone give me some jquery to do this? Also "/My/Website" has to be changed to something different for each li...is this possible?

Comment: It is all possible, but you are not clear on `how` it sill be different for each li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using each, you can give each li span.mad a different website url

```
$("li span.mad").each(function(i,e) {
 $(e).html(
    "<a href='/My/Website/"+ (i+1) +"'>"+$(e).html()+"</a>");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6EzDs/

(or using `wrap`)

```
$("li span.mad").each(function(i,e) {
 $(e).wrap("<a href='/My/Website/"+ (i+1) +"' />");
});
```

Comment: I need to add the span tag first to the li...then do this process how do I add a new span tag and class to each li first?

Comment: @nick edit your question if it does not start with <li><span>.. That's my interpretation of what the starting point is.

Answer (score 1):

Give each li a unique class name and use the wrapp function

```
$('span .class1').wrap('<a href="class1 url"/>')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("span.mad").wrap("<a href='/My/Website' />");
```

Or, if you want to go by id instead of class name

```
$("#someSpanID").wrap("<a href='/My/Website' />");
```

Comment: Can I iterate through the li's and add something different for '/My/Website'

Comment: Yes - see @cyberkiwi's answer below